# How to get those tuples from a list of tuples which have the same second value?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples which look like below

```
entities = [('tmp', 'warm'), ('loc', 'blr'), ('cap', 'blr'), ('aps', 'yes'), ('date', '12-10-2018')]
```

I want to store those tuples which have the same **second** values. As you can see, the tuples `('loc', 'blr')` and `('cap', 'blr')` have the same second value.

I want these two tuples to be stored in a list for me to refer.

This is what I tried but it doesn't work as expected

```
duplicate = []
for i in range(len(entities)):
    for j in range(1, len(entities)):
        if entities[i][1] == entities[j][1]:
            duplicate.append([entities[i][1], entities[j][1]])
            break
```

But I get all the tuples as if all tuples have same second value. How can I accomplish this?

**Desired output**

```
('loc', 'blr'), ('cap', 'blr')
```

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: @user5173426 added desired output

Answer (score 1):

You could group together lists with common second elements in the following way:

```
s = sorted(entities, key = lambda x: x[1])
[list(v) for k,v in groupby(s, key=lambda x: x[1])]

[[('date', '12-10-2018')],
 [('loc', 'blr'), ('cap', 'blr')],
 [('tmp', 'warm')],
 [('aps', 'yes')]]
```

If performance is an issue consider using [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html):

```
from operator import itemgetter
s = sorted(entities, key = itemgetter(1))
[list(v) for k,v in groupby(s, key = itemgetter(1))]

[[('date', '12-10-2018')],
 [('loc', 'blr'), ('cap', 'blr')],
 [('tmp', 'warm')],
 [('aps', 'yes')]]
```

Now, if you only want to keet cases where two tuples had a common second element, you can do:

```
[i for i in l if len(i)>1]
[[('loc', 'blr'), ('cap', 'blr')]]
```

I proposed this answer so that this way you can extend this to `n` common elements in the second place, as you may have more than 2.

Comment: Exacly ! , tip:  instead of lambda the `operator.itemgetter(1)` could be also used.

Comment: Yes will also add that, as it performs better for large lists. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

You can use O(*n* log *n*) [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) (requires pre-sorting your input list), but O(*n*) [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) is sufficient:

```
from collections import Counter
from operator import itemgetter

# construct dictionary mapping second value to count
c = Counter(map(itemgetter(1), entities))

# filter for second values with count > 1
dups = {value for value, count in c.items() if count > 1}

# filter entities with second value in dups
res = [entity for entity in entities if entity[1] in dups]

print(res)
# [('loc', 'blr'), ('cap', 'blr')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group these tuples using dict for a more common case

```
grouped = {}
for k, v in entities:
    grouped[v].setdefault(k, []).append((k, v))
for _, tuples in grouped.items():
    if len(tuples) > 2:
        print(tuples)
```

all pairs with same second value will be grouped under different keys